# Custom angular 7 library with ionic 4 - Can't resolve '../@ionic/angular/dist/core.ngfactory' build prod error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-library

We have built small angular 7/ionic 4 library that we want to use in multiple projects internally by installing through git url. Serving the project works correctly, all imports from library work fine. But when running `ng build --prod` I get the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/edetail-core/edetail-core.ngfactory.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../@ionic/angular/dist/core.ngfactory' in '/Users/user.name/Documents/ionic/edetails/node_modules/edetail-core'
```

I've tried different set ups - moving everything to devDependencies (main package.json), adding and removing packages from peerDependencies (library package.json). adding

```
"lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts",
    "externals": "@ionic/angular"
  }
```

(lib ng-package.json) but nothing helped. IonicModule gets imported from `'@ionic/angular'` in the main library module file (edetail-core.module.ts).

Here is ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/edetail-core",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts"
  }
}
```

library package.json

```
{
  "name": "edetail-core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

main package.json

```
{
  "name": "edetail-core",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve edetail-test",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",        
    "npm-pack": "cd dist/edetail-core && npm pack",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "scss-bundle": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": ">=0.34.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @RemiSture no, not yet, got pulled away to another project temporarily, so still looking for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add line `"@ionic/*": ["node_modules/@ionic/*"]` to paths in your tsconfig.json / tsconfig.app.json files

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"],
            "@ionic/*": ["node_modules/@ionic/*"],
            ...
         }
    }
    ...
}
```